# Encrypting an Arraylist in Java

Tags: java, encryption, aes

How can i encrypt an Arraylist in java using AES 128 bit encryption. It gives an error

```
public static  ArrayList<EnteredDetails> encrypt(ArrayList<EnteredDetails> Data) throws Exception {
    Key key = generateKey();
    Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGO);
    c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
    ArrayList<EnteredDetails> encVal = c.doFinal(Data);

   //no suitable method found for doFinal

    return encVal;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encryption acts on bytes (`byte[]` or streams) and not on full objects.

So you need to convert your objects into bytes some way. [Serialization](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/objects/serial.html) is the most obvious way.